# how can I remove all the indenting chars when I use toString() to convert xml object in coldfusion?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, tostring

I am coding with coldfusion, now I an trying to use toString() to convert a xml structure generated from xmlParse() into XML string, but the toString() always add some chr(10) and chr(32) between xml node, for example "<node1>xxx</node1>chr(10)chr(32)chr(32)chr(32)<node2>yyyy</node2>", they looks like keep the indenting, so my question is how can I remove all of these indenting chars? (I need to keep the same char inside node content, so using regular expression to strip all doesn't work for this case. )

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call toString( xml ), internally it's using Cast._String() which wraps String.valueOf() which wraps NodeImpl.toString() method on the org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl class.

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl.html#toString()

The .toString() method gives you a non-dom copy of the data for debugging purposes.

As to why it's injecting CRLFs etc, I'm not sure. I'll have a poke around and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Chr(10) is a line feed and 32 is a space, so yes it is just formatting.

When you write the content of the variable that you put the output from toString, the ColdFusion chr functions will vanish leaving you with perfectly valid xml.

Like Mike, I am a bit confused as to why they are appearing though. Are you wrapping the output in a xmlformat or similar? If you are, don't. Xmlformat is only intended for the content of a node not the full structure.